# Build Error - After upgrade to Spring boot 3 Getting Unresolved reference for path in org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-criteria, java-17, build-error, hibernate-6.x

I have upgraded all my project dependencies in gradle to spring boot 3 compatible.
for ex: springframewor.boot version to 3.0.7 and Hibernate-core version to 6.1.7 final, java version to 17. During application build i am getting Unresolved reference for path in the import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath

a piece of code snippet using singularAttributePath is below:

```
val expression = getMethod.invoke(root,filterCriteria.field) as SingularAttributePath<*>
```

i am getting Unresolved reference for SingularAttributePath in the above code.

what is the implementation for SingularAttributePath in Hibernate 6?